# RVM fails to clone ruby 1.9.2 head from github

Tags: git, github, rvm, head, ruby-1.9.2

I've been wanting to install the latest version of ruby 1.9.2 through RVM but it fails when trying to fetch the sources from github:

```
albookpro-3:~ pl$ rvm install 1.9.2-head
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/pl/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-head - #fetching 
Cloning from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/pl/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head/.git/ shallow over http or ftp not supported
cloning from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git failed, now attempting to clone from https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection...
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/pl/.rvm/repos/ruby-1.9.2-head/.git/
Cannot get remote repository information.
Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to fetch the repository.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

When looking for known versions:

```
albookpro-3:~ pl$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.6-head
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p334]
[ruby-]1.8.7-head
[ruby-]1.9.1-p378
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.1-head
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p180]
[ruby-]1.9.2-head
ruby-head

...
```

But it did work when I fetch version 1.9.2-p180 that I am using right now.

Anything I should do to make this work? 
I'm using the latest rvm version:

```
albookpro-3:~ pl$ rvm -v

rvm 1.6.20 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of git do you have? It could be related to this: https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days

Comment: I was using 1.5.5, indeed, upgrading to 1.7.5.4 seem to fix the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had analogous problem with git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/mg/Downloads/1/CHDataStructures/.git/
Cannot get remote repository information.
Perhaps git-update-server-info needs to be run there?
$  git-update-server-info 
fatal: Not a git repository
```

It's interesting that on the same computer it did not work under Ubuntu Hardy and worked under Lucid.

And this is what helped:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures.git
```

(that is, I replaced https: with git:, and it worked)